# Allowing jurisdiction tags on answers

Tags: feature-request, jurisdiction

Law is one of those areas (perhaps even more than travel) where I feel there is a potential for a dramatically different exchange format.

The distinction: The same legal question has different answers depending on where you live, act, store your data, etc.

Has anyone considered allowing ANSWERS to be tagged with jurisdictions where QUESTIONS are not?  Jurisdictions could even be geotagged so that users could query by their locale (both to answer and ask).

Although the user interface might look quite different, I think the Stack Exchange model could be very useful: Encouraging civil discussion, focusing on questions of enduring value, focusing on quality questions and answers.

So far I have found:

- [Asking the same question for a new jurisdiction is allowed.](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365/asking-a-question-for-a-different-jurisdiction)
- My proposal has been already proposed [in response](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/493/26904) to a [suggestion to restrict jurisdictions](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/490/jurisdiction-relevance-to-questions)

Comment: By the way, I kind of like this "new contributor" badge -- even though I have 1k points on the main site...

Comment: And of course, feature requests are vetted by the company, not by upvotes on Meta, but I'd like to get the idea out there anyway.

Comment: Allowing? I think we should probably require them. So many question are unanswerable because there's no jurisdiction provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You have to bring this up at the main Meta.

I don't believe it's up to Law on whether or not something like this is implemented.

If you think this is important, you may want to file this issue at https://meta.stackexchange.com/, however, please be advised that they downvote *very* heavily on that meta.

I do agree that something like this may be pretty useful, but I'd imagine it'd have to be a pretty significant deviation from existing flow, and is unlikely to be implemented.

Comment: Unless my question receives significant upvotes here, I won't take it to Meta.  I think the Law community would need to want it pretty badly to make it worth taking to the SO company.

Comment: @JosiahYoder, TBH, I think it's a very worthy change, but I highly doubt it'll get implemented.

Answer (score 3):

This is allowed now, altogether not with the same interface One can include a "Tag:xyz" in square brackets in an answer. I usually put it at the top, and it displays and i think functions as i tag. I do this when posting an answer limited to a specific jurisdiction to a question not so limited.

For example, see my answer to [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/44962/can-a-soldier-enforce-federal-law)

Comment: Can you share an example answer where you did this? Then I can confirm that search-by-tag works.

Comment: @Josiah Yoder I have linked one such example in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, [Searching within the tag does not reveal your question](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunited-states%5D+Indeed+under+the+Posse+Comititas+Act) even though [your question can be found alone](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=Indeed+under+the+Posse+Comititas+Act). This makes tagging questions less useful -- one cannot search by jurisdiction.  It is, however, a solution when the question did not specify a jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

### This is unlikely to happen

The way tags operate is not site specific. This change would require allowing tags on all stack exchange sites and, I would hazard a guess, significant programming time. There seems to be no call for this elsewhere so your idea is probably stillborn.

Of course you can [tag](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) your own [answers](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answers) as [much](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/much) as you [like](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/like).

Comment: Can you share an example answer where you did this? Then I can confirm that search-by-tag works.